# error CS0234: The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, namespaces

I have seen so many QA about this error, but none of them solved my issue,
Here we go:
I have this namespace: `Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SpatialAwareness.Processing`
[image]
Which is included in a DLL called: `Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.PlaneFinding`
[image]
Now, there is a second DLL called `Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SDK`
Which is referencing the first DLL, and also defines a constant called `PLANE_FINDING_PRESENT` the somehow relates to it (Here are some photos from the inspector and VS to show what i mean)
[image]
[image]

Inside of the DLL called `Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SDK` there is a file called `SurfaceMeshesToPlanes`
In this file i am attempting to be using the namespace `Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SpatialAwareness.Processing` like so:
[image]
I am expecting this whole thing to work but i am getting error:
`Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@2eb95bb1aae9-1646916095499\SDK\Experimental\SpatialAwareness\SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.cs(13,55): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Processing' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SpatialAwareness' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
Any thoughts?

Comment: Unless you're in .NET Core you'r gonna to reference both assemblies afaik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the **platforms** section in the desired dll, once i changed it to `any` it became visible to the other dll
[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This helped.  Any for anyone who wants to set "any platform, edit the asmdef with a text editor and remove all include & exclude platforms.